# message coming from tcp socket processed in chunks not as a whole

Tags: spring, sockets, integration, message

I am trying to establish a tcp socket connection to a spring integraton gateway.  The byte arrat messages are rather large and I have setup the ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer to handle it by modding the property maxMessageSize to handle the messages.  However, the messages are instead being handled in chunks, the first only 28 bytes in size before the service-activator is called.  I know that there is an Aggregator that could be used but I was thinking I might have setup the integration components incorrectly.  I am using the basic spring jars 3.0.5 and the integration 2.0.2 and the integrationContext.xml is here:

Does anyone have any suggestions
Thanks

Comment: You might have been down voted because people expect to see code in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source had a mangled header value which gave a false reading as to the size of the message coming.  Once the header was fixed there was no problem.